# google marker filter using javascript from json data

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have this json object:

```
{
   "tcu_pos_list": [
      {
         "latitude":"23",
         "tcu_id":1,
         "longitude":"23"
      },
      {
         "latitude":"11",
         "tcu_id":4,
         "longitude":"11"
      },
      {
         "latitude":"3",
         "tcu_id":5,
         "longitude":"34"
      }
   ]
}
```

In order to set all the markers in the map I create this function:

```
var map;
var marker = [];

function setMarker() {
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/locator/tcu/position/', function(car_pos) {

        for (var i = 0; i < car_pos["tcu_pos_list"].length; i++){

            marker [i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
            });

            var userLat = car_pos["tcu_pos_list"][i].latitude;
            var userLon = car_pos["tcu_pos_list"][i].longitude;
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLon);
            marker[i].setPosition(position);
            map.setCenter(position);

        }
    });
}
```

I want to check if my Json object has new positions so I check it every 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
    setMarker();
}, 5000);
```

This is working good, the problem is when I try to filter a google marker. The idea is to select a tcu_id and display only that marker position.

For that in a html selector I create a function onchange.

```
<div class="select-style">
    <select id="Selector" onchange="filter_tcu()">
        <option value="">Please select
        <option value="1">1
        <option value="4">4
        <option value="5">5
    </select>
</div>

<script>
function filter_tcu() {
    var tcu_id = document.getElementById("Selector").value;
    console.log(tcu_id)

    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/locator/tcu/position/', function(car_pos) {

        for (var i = 0; i < car_pos["tcu_pos_list"].length; i++){

            if( tcu_id == car_pos["tcu_pos_list"][i].tcu_id) {

                marker [i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                });

                var userLat = car_pos["tcu_pos_list"][i].latitude;
                var userLon = car_pos["tcu_pos_list"][i].longitude;
                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLon);
                marker[i].setPosition(position);
                map.setCenter(position);
            }

            else {
                marker [i].setMap(null);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

When I select a value the marker is filtered but after 5 seconds (set Interval) all markers are shown again. I would be gratefull if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of your setMarker function.

Update your setInterval to just call the filter_tcu instead.

Update the filter_tcu function to check if no filter is selected, just display the marker.  e.g.

```
if (tcu_id.length == 0 || tcu_id == car_pos["tcu_pos_list"][i].tcu_id) {
```